# Delay method call while user still typing

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

I've got a search box in my MAUI XAML page which calls a method in the ViewModel. The amount of data it has to filter from the database is huge and every time the user types a letter it takes a few seconds to respond with results. I want to delay the method call eg. 1s and when the user stops typing (doesn't type more than 1s) then it calls the filtering method.

```xml
<!-- Search box -->
<Border StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="Transparent" Background="Transparent">
    <dxe:TextEdit EndIcon="search" 
                  PlaceholderText="Search"  
                  TextChangedCommand="{Binding FilterChangedCommand}"  
                  TextChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}"  
                  TextFontSize="14"  
                  TextVerticalAlignment="Center"  
                  BorderThickness="1"  
                  BoxPadding="20,6,10,6"  
                  CornerRadius="16"  
                  HeightRequest="35"  
                  Margin="15,10,15,10"/>
</Border>
```

How can I do this in MAUI?

Comment: One approach is to create a timer that is restarted on every button press, do the work in its tick-event, and then stop the timer. But I'm not familiar with the MAUI timers.

Comment: It is called _debouncing_ an event, may this help to you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.extensions.dispatchertimerextensions.debounce?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-6.1

Comment: @MonsieurMerso, I see this is for UWP. Is it also implemented for MAUI?

Comment: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example.html#3-create-viewmodels - the magic happens in the ViewModel so it does not matter if the UI is WPF, MAUI, UWP or anything else which is aware of binding

Answer (score 3):

This technique is called debouncing. The .NET MAUI Community Toolkit offers a ready-to-use [Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/behaviors?view=net-maui-8.0) for that which is called the [UserStoppedTypingBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/user-stopped-typing-behavior).

An example could look like this:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MyLittleApp.MainPage">
     
           <dxe:TextEdit EndIcon="search" PlaceholderText="Search" TextChangedCommand="{Binding FilterChangedCommand}" TextChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" TextFontSize="14" TextVerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" BoxPadding="20,6,10,6" CornerRadius="16" HeightRequest="35" Margin="15,10,15,10">
                <dxe:TextEdit.Behaviors>
                    <toolkit:UserStoppedTypingBehavior 
                        Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                        StoppedTypingTimeThreshold="1000"
                        MinimumLengthThreshold="3"
                        ShouldDismissKeyboardAutomatically="True" />
                </dxe:TextEdit.Behaviors>
            </dxe:TextEdit>
</ContentPage>
```

This assumes that your `dxe:TextEdit` component supports Behaviors. If not, you can look at the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit code for this and implement your own mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Another decent way to do it is with any suitable WatchdogTimer such as the one referenced in comment.

```
// <PackageReference Include="IVSoftware.Portable.WatchdogTimer" Version="1.2.1" />
WatchdogTimer _wdtEntry = new WatchdogTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };

public string EntryText
{
    get => _entryText;
    set
    {
        if (!Equals(_entryText, value))
        {
            _entryText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EntryText))
            {
                _wdtEntry.Cancel();
            }
            else
            {
                _wdtEntry.StartOrRestart(action: () =>
                {
                    OverlayText = GenerateFilterCommand();
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
string _entryText = string.Empty;
```

---

The flexibility of this approach can be demoed by waiting for a restartable 1-second interval to expire before showing an overlay with a mock generated sql command. Then (for this demo) the overlay itself is timed with another instance (not shown in the snippet above). Finally a third WDT instance is attached to the click button and likewise displays a message when the user stops clicking for a certain amount of time. Fun with timers, anyway, and lots of ways to achieve the objective.

[image: demo]

---

**Demo code**

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EntryWithWDT"
             x:Class="EntryWithWDT.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageBindingContext/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollView>
            <VerticalStackLayout
                Spacing="25"
                Padding="30,0"
                VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Image
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <Entry 
                    Text="{Binding EntryText}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEntryEnabled}"
                    WidthRequest="300"/>
                <Button
                    Text="{Binding ButtonText}"
                    Command="{Binding IncrementCountCommand}"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="300" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <Grid 
            IsVisible="{Binding OverlayVisible}"
            BackgroundColor="Gray"
            Opacity=".95"
            RowDefinitions="*,Auto,*"
            InputTransparent="False">
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OverlayTapped}" />
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label 
                Text="{Binding OverlayText}"
                Grid.Row="1"
                WidthRequest="300"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                Padding="10"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

---

```
using IVSoftware.Portable;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace EntryWithWDT
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        new MainPageBindingContext BindingContext => (MainPageBindingContext)base.BindingContext;
    }
    class MainPageBindingContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainPageBindingContext()
        {
            IncrementCountCommand = new Command(onIncrementCount);
            OverlayTappedCommand = new Command((o)=>_wdtOverlay.Cancel());
        }
        public ICommand SetCountCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand IncrementCountCommand { get; private set; }
        private void onIncrementCount(object o)
        {
            Count++;
            _wdtCount.StartOrRestart(initialAction: () => _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(),
            completeAction: () =>
            {
                _stopwatch.Stop();
                var message = $"User stopped clicking after {_stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"ss\:fff")}";
                OverlayText = message;

                // Show overlay briefly
                _wdtOverlay.StartOrRestart(
                    initialAction: () => OverlayVisible = true, 
                    completeAction: () =>OverlayVisible = false);
            });
        }
        public ICommand OverlayTappedCommand { get; private set; }

        WatchdogTimer _wdtCount = new WatchdogTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5) };
        Stopwatch _stopwatch;
        public string ButtonText
        {
            get => _buttonText;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_buttonText, value))
                {
                    _buttonText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        string _buttonText = "Click me";
        public int Count
        {
            get => _count;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_count, value))
                {
                    _count = value;
                    if (Count == 0)
                    {
                        ButtonText = "Click me";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ButtonText = $"Clicked {Count} times";
                    }
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        int _count = default;

        public bool OverlayVisible
        {
            get => _overlayVisible;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_overlayVisible, value))
                {
                    _overlayVisible = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        bool _overlayVisible = default;

        public string EntryText
        {
            get => _entryText;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_entryText, value))
                {
                    _entryText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EntryText))
                    {
                        _wdtEntry.Cancel();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _wdtEntry.StartOrRestart(action: () =>
                        {
                            OverlayText = GenerateFilterCommand();
                            // Show overlay briefly
                            _wdtOverlay.StartOrRestart(
                                initialAction: () =>
                                {
                                    IsEntryEnabled = false;
                                    OverlayVisible = true;
                                },
                                completeAction: () =>
                                {
                                    OverlayVisible = false;
                                    IsEntryEnabled = true;
                                }
                             );
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        string _entryText = string.Empty;

        // <PackageReference Include="IVSoftware.Portable.WatchdogTimer" Version="1.2.1" />
        WatchdogTimer _wdtEntry = new WatchdogTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
        WatchdogTimer _wdtOverlay = new WatchdogTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
        private string GenerateFilterCommand()
        {
            var where = string.Join(
                "\nAND\n", 
                EntryText.Split(' ')
                .Select(_=>_.Trim())
                .Where(_=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_))
                .Select(_ => $"desc LIKE'%{_}%'"));
            var sql = $"SELECT * FROM items \nWHERE {where}";
            return sql;
        }

        public string OverlayText
        {
            get => _overlayText;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_overlayText, value))
                {
                    _overlayText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        string _overlayText = string.Empty;

        public bool IsEntryEnabled
        {
            get => _isEntryEnabled;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_isEntryEnabled, value))
                {
                    _isEntryEnabled = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        bool _isEntryEnabled = true;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/EntryWithWDT.git)